# fprintf printing garbage characters

Tags: c

I have the following block of code:

```
while(true){
      if(feof(stdin)!=0){
        break;
      }
      fgets(fileText2,1000,stdin);
      //flag E
      if(strchr(flags,'A')||strchr(flags,'E')){
        if(fileText2!=NULL&&strlen(fileText2)>0){
          fileText2[strlen(fileText2)-1]='$';
          fileText2[strlen(fileText2)]='\n';
          fileText2[strlen(fileText2)+1]='\0';
        }
      }
      
      fprintf(stdout,"%s",fileText2);
      memset(fileText2,0,1000);
    }
```

I am redirecting the contents of a file to the standard input using the `<` operator.

The file looks like:

```
omcunneecnucnwencnwecwe
cwec
c
wc
wec
wc
wec
wec
ecwccwc
wec
wecw we
ew
 e
 wecwe
c we e ewwe   ewwe
w
 we
wec
ec


ceec
```

and is a unix line termination file.
The first line it prints the `omcunneecnucnwencnwecwe`, but before printing the second sentence (`cwec`), it prints some garbage characters.
This only happens after the first line, and all others are fine.

The following is an example of the output:

```
omcunneecnucnwencnwecwe$
h_cwec$
c$
wc$
wec$
wc$
wec$
wec$
ecwccwc  $
wec$
wecw we $
ew$
 e$
 wecwe$
c we e ewwe   ewwe $
w$
 we$
wec$
ec$
$
$
ceec$
```

How do I get rid of those garbage characters? (The dollar characters are not garbage, only the second line ones before the actual sentence in the file)

EDIT: `fileText2` is defined as `char fileText2[1000];`

Comment: just did, forgot when was posting.

Comment: See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359)

Comment: I do check for the possibility of one more iteration in the line `strlen(fileText2)>0`. Also, if anything, I would think it would give me a problem in the last line, not in the second.

Comment: Duarte Arribas `strlen(fileText2)>0` is too late to certainly work right.  Check the return of `fgets()`.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This overwrites the trailing *null character*.

```
fileText2[strlen(fileText2)]='\n';
```

Now `strlen(fileText2)` below is bad as `fileText2` is no longer certainly null character terminated - not a *string*.

```
fileText2[strlen(fileText2)+1]='\0';  // UB
```

---

When `fgets()` return `NULL` (when end-of-file occurs),

```
fgets(fileText2,1000,stdin);
```

Then the following `strlen(fileText2)` reflects the previous line.

Instead:

```
//while(true){
//  if(feof(stdin)!=0){
//    break;
//  }
//  fgets(fileText2,1000,stdin);
while (fgets(fileText2, sizeof fileText2, stdin)) {
  ...
```